Not able to upload File in angular 17.0.7
when i am trying to send the file to backend server i data is going empty
i am using FormData and using append method to insert data into FormData , but when i console and see i am getting empty object.
html code
<input (change)="handleFileUpload($event)" id="uploadFile" type="file" style="display: none" />

ts
handleFileUpload(event: any) {
const file = event.target.files[0];
this.selectedFile = file;
this.fileName = file.name;

const selectedFileSize = file.size / 1024;

if (selectedFileSize < 1024) {
  this.fileSize = `${selectedFileSize.toFixed(2)} KB`;
} else {
  this.fileSize = `${(selectedFileSize / 1024).toFixed(2)} MB`;
}
}



sendUploadedFile() {
this.fileUploadApiStatus = this.apiStatusConstants.inProgress;

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_name', this.fileName);
formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);
formData.append('size', this.fileSize);
console.log(formData);

this.apiServices.uploadFile(formData).subscribe({
    next: (response: any) => {
      // console.log('Response from file upload', response);
      this.fileUploadApiStatus = this.apiStatusConstants.success;
    },

    error: (err: any) => {
      this.fileUploadApiStatus = this.apiStatusConstants.failure;
    },
  });
}


is the payload sent properly in the network tab? you have a typo formData0 also please share the contents of uploadFile!

There might be some issue in backend code, could you please provide more details about your backend endpoint.

uploadFile(data: any): Observable {     const projectId = this.getProjectId();     const apiUrl = url;     console.log(data.get('file'));     console.log(data);      const boundary = Boundary-${Math.random().toString(16).substring(2)};     const headers = this.getHeaders(       multipart/form-data ; boundary = ${boundary} ); return this.http.post(apiUrl, data, { headers }); }

easier to just do:  let form = document.getElementById('your-forms-id')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);  Then post the formData to your endpoint.   Also note that when sending FormData object, you don't need to set boundaries or headers, those are set automatically.

It's fine to see an empty object. Try to be more specific
console.log(formData.get('file'));

You should be able to see File {}
Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wrdqmi?file=src%2Fmain.ts

I am able to see File {} and when i try to console i am able to see that data.but when i check the payload while sending it to backend the payload object is empty => FormData(0).
when i worked in react and try to send files i can see the data in the payload
FormData(1) with the data

uploadFile(data: any): Observable<any> {     const projectId = this.getProjectId();     const apiUrl = url`;
console.log(data.get('file'));
console.log(data);
const boundary = `Boundary-${Math.random().toString(16).substring(2)}`;
const headers = this.getHeaders(
  `multipart/form-data ; boundary = ${boundary}`
);

return this.http.post(apiUrl, data, { headers });

}`
